# accepting user data from users and displaying it

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, forms

I am new to web programming. I am currently using an html form which accepts data (many fields with different datatypes eg. date) and add it to mysql server using php and display everyones form submission in a tabular form. For a change I wanted to try something different,  database alternative to mysql which is fast and natively accessible like json but at the same time more secure. I am also tired of html forms and would like to automatically generate them from a template eg. mysql table columns for a partucular table. I am interested in trying something different. I would be also interested in open source ~cms alternatives which I can customise later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider CMS tools like [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org), which abstracts away most of the manual coding needed to perform data capture.